# app.getDeviceLocation() always returning null

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I have successfully asked the user for permission to get their coarse device and I have checked that `app.isPermissionGranted()` transitions from false to true after the user allows permission, but whenever I use `app.getDeviceLocation()`, it simply returns `null`. My Google Home that I test on gives my correct location when I ask, "Where am I?"

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    function askDate(app) {
            console.log('Permission:', app.isPermissionGranted()); //says true
            if (app.isPermissionGranted()) {
                //this always says null
                console.log('User device location:', JSON.stringify(app.getDeviceLocation())); 
                app.ask('thanks for the location!');
            } else {
                app.tell('You need to allow me to access your location to give an accurate recommendation');
            }
        }

function askForLocPermission(app) {
            console.log('Permission:', app.isPermissionGranted()); //says false
            let permission = app.SupportedPermissions.DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION;
            app.data.permission = permission;
            app.askForPermission('To get weather near you', permission); //asks user for permission to get their zip code
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up testing it with `app.SupportedPermissions.DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION` and that worked gave me my coordinates no problem. I hope Google fixes the bug for coarse locations if there is one.